# Android studio giving R error while building project

Tags: android, android-layout, bitmap, android-studio-2.0

In my project I am using Bitmap for adding background images. My code was working fine when I use a second bitmap. As soon as I inflate second bitmap project starts giving R error while building. 
Below is my code :

```
@Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {

    bg = new Background(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.imageOne));
    newbg = new AnotherClass(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.imageTwo));

   // thread.setRunning(true);
   // thread.start();

}
```

Things I have tried :

- cleaned project both from Build Clean as well as terminal.
- Rebuild the project.
- Restart with invalidate caches .

> Broken pipe
>              java.io.IOException: Broken pipe
>              at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.write0(Native Method)
>              at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write(SocketDispatcher.java:47)
>              at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.writeFromNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:93)
>              at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(IOUtil.java:65)
>              at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.write(SocketChannelImpl.java:471)
>              at com.android.ddmlib.JdwpPacket.write(JdwpPacket.java:179)
>              at com.android.ddmlib.Client.send(Client.java:654)
>              at com.android.ddmlib.jdwp.JdwpAgent.send(JdwpAgent.java:92)
>              at com.android.ddmlib.HandleHeap.sendREAQ(HandleHeap.java:349)
>              at com.android.ddmlib.Client.requestAllocationStatus(Client.java:517)
>              at com.android.ddmlib.DeviceMonitor.createClient(DeviceMonitor.java:573)
>              at com.android.ddmlib.DeviceMonitor.openClient(DeviceMonitor.java:545)
>              at com.android.ddmlib.DeviceMonitor.deviceClientMonitorLoop(DeviceMonitor.java:361)
>              at com.android.ddmlib.DeviceMonitor.access$100(DeviceMonitor.java:65)
>              at com.android.ddmlib.DeviceMonitor$1.run(DeviceMon...

Comment: clean project and rebuild it

Comment: you can also try to call gradle assembleDebug --stacktrace from Android studio console

Comment: @KhizarHayat I have cleaned project many times, still no result

Comment: @Robert doesn't work man

Comment: Does lint returns any information about errors?

Comment: In **Terminal** view run `gradle build --stacktrace --debug --info`, and post the output error.

Comment: updated question with error log @Robert

Comment: @GueorguiObregon tried ,still facing same

Comment: see my answer below@rahulsharma

Comment: @rahulsharma if you remove second bitmap, the error disappear?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you mentioned your code was working fine until you added second one , so the problem lies withing your second bitmap.

The might have occurred if you had used an image which was manually converted , For example : image.jpg converted to image.png .

**Solution : Refactor the image name to its original one and use it.If you want to convert it then use image extension change tools,(many available online.) and then use that in your bitmap.**

Hopefully it will work. :)

Comment: Thanks man it worked, I actually am using a jpg file as png. Your solution works like charm :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Android Studio try to `Build->Clean Project` and then  `Build->Rebuild Project`

Comment: Maybe is failing when trying to assemble

Answer (score 0):

you should close your Android studio or eclipse whatever you are using. If not solved your error then do `adb kill-server && sleep 5 && adb devices` and then start your tool (Eclipse/Ant/AS) again.

Comment: I am using studio, with LG device

Comment: Did you close your studio and try again?